# Jasper Reports and net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.flexible.row.height and pagination in DOCX exporter format

Tags: jasper-reports, docx

The problem starts, where in jasper reports and docx exporter we resize the paginated table. The table afterwards continues on non-paginated page and a lot of empty space is on new page.
How we achieve to have net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.flexible.row.height=true and page properly and dynamically paginated even, when user resize some rows in table?

**Table properly generated to DOCX:**
[image: Table properly generated to DOCX]

**Bad pagination after some cells are resized in DOCX table by user:**
[image: Bad pagination after some cells are resized in DOCX table by user.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think jasper reports are not having such an functionality. As DOCX exporter is using grid to export data to DOCX, the resulting table in DOCX is not an DOCX table as DOCX object, but grid of small tables with text. So when in such document user will resize some cell, the pagination is broken and others gird tables go over document pages. So document is not properly paginated. Anyway in most cases reporting as targeting to objective to export to read only forms for printing etc ...